# Who are Gramadevathas found especially in South India?

Tags: shiva, puranas, culture, parvati, shakti

Common names of these Gramadevathas are Ankamma, Poleramma etc.

- What is their relation to Lord Shiva?
- Can we Worship Lord Shiva along with Gramadevathas? See this [blog](http://mudiraja.com/mudiraju_ankamma.html).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankalamma

Comment: this wikipedia page doesn't answer all my questions.

Comment: Grama devathas are presiding deities of villages. They are aspects of Shakti and are usually worshipped with pOtarAju (considered the grama devata's brother) who is said to be an aspect of Vishnu. I don't know much about goat sacrifices so can't answer that part.

Comment: @moonstar2001  There's story on net that Grama devatas hate people who worship Shiva. Do you believe in that story?  http://mudiraja.com/mudiraju_ankamma.html.

Comment: Never heard that story and I have no idea re: its origins. Even if it were true, one must not forget that the goddess' fury was a result of strife meted out to devotees. It is probably a hyperbolic representation of the goddess' love and protective nature towards devotees. In general, I do not believe grama devatas hate Shiva or his worshippers. Specific curses may exist where the devata may have cursed the the village for a certain period of time(can be centuries) for the wrongdoings of the villagers. In general, if such a story is in existence, it may be better to err on the side of caution.

Comment: @TheDestroyer You can worship shiva without hesitation, he is vedic God and Ruler of Bhuloka. People Spread Different superstitions its upto you to ignore them or to follow them. Have faith In Divine, and just follow your path that is what Sharanagti is all about (as said by Shri Krishna in Bhagwad Gita).

Comment: As far as I know, Ankalaamman is the same as this devi:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angalaamman